# Is this a testing tool for android development? What's the name of it?

Tags: android

[image]

I'm a Java fan learning Android development recently using Genymotion and Intellij IDEA. I always see the below icon (looks like Shrek:)) on Stack Overflow and other websites, but I have no idea what it is, I'm guessing it is a testing tool for Android. Unfortunately I don't know how to google search it without its name.

Can anyone please tell me the name of this app, and what it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the icon that shows when usb debugging is enabled.

Comment: I was using my android device for testing my android app in  `developer mode`, did not see such icon...

Comment: If usb debugging is enabled, and you plug your device into a computer, this icon appears. It's that simple, really.